# Finding uninitialized variables before running script

Tags: python, compilation, ide, initialization, wing-ide

How do I detect whether all variables have been initialized in a Python script before running the script? Ideally, I would like my compiler (currently [Wing IDE](https://wingware.com/)) to detect errors as part of the build/compilation process. This is to prevent the program from crashing after ~30min of loading data etc. due to a simple mistake.

I know that Python can manipulate variable in all sorts of ways. However, my scripts tend to be fairly simple and I do not expect the method to be bullet-proof.

As an example I'd like the error detection method to find simple errors such as the misspelling of `grocery_bill` in the script below.

```
prices = {'apple': 0.40, 'banana': 0.50}
my_purchase = {
    'apple': 1,
    'banana': 6}
grocery_bill = sum(prices[fruit] * my_purchase[fruit]
                   for fruit in my_purchase)
print 'I owe the grocer $%.2f' % grocery_blil
```

Comment: Does Wing IDE not already do this?

Comment: Perhaps. I haven't been able to find an option that does this.

Comment: Doesn't it just crash and tell you the line error when you do this?

Comment: In fact, running python on terminal gives me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print 'I owe the grocer $%.2f' % grocery_blil
NameError: name 'grocery_blil' is not defined

Comment: Yes, of course. The whole idea is to find the error before the script crashes as most of my scripts take 5 min to 24 hours. I've updated my question to make this more clear :)

Comment: I just want to say that the fact that this is not default behavior in Python is unbelievably irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a two options I can currently think of.

1. [PyLint](https://www.logilab.org/857)

This tool can analyse all your source code and try to detect places where bugs may be happening. This should detect things like the one you have mentioned.

2. [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

This is an IDE by Jetbrains, and you can turn on spell check for all your variables. While this does not stop typos from happening, it does make it far easier to catch them.

If you're a student, you can get the full version of PyCharm for free.

Comment: I've found that Wing IDE has integration with PyLint: http://www.wingware.com/doc/edit/pylint

Comment: Yea, right now the PyLint tool is the way to do this (usually after configuring it not to show the many less useful messages).  We'll try to add showing this on the fly on the editor.  The history behind this is we've focused a lot more on test-driven and debugger-driven development than up-front compiler-like behavior.  But obviously this is a feature that should be added.